# vr - targeting different platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I'm wondering whether there are major differences between vr hardware/software integration. For instance, if I use unity to create a game, and want to target all platforms, is there any benefit to targeting one platform over the other? (oculus, htc)

In other words, can I get the htc vr hardware, and then still target oculus and know that it will all work correctly? or do I have to get all hardware that I will target?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes.  But in saying that, a good developer should at least test with known market popular hardware.

> *"[Unity VR adds the ability to target VR devices from directly within Unity without the need for external plugins. It provides a base API and featureset with the goal of forward compatibility for devices and software. **The provided API surface today is minimal by design, and will expand** as we learn more about the needs of VR developers.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html)"*.

I note that currently only *Oculus* and *Playstation VR* [are listed](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRDeviceType.html).

Now one should be testing a console game directly anyway and not just the desktop.  i.e. if making a PS4 game, don't test the VR aspects on desktop with Oculus.

Hypothetically if Unity includes say Steam VR then a game developer with only Oculus should be somewhat comfortable in the thought it should work too on Steam in much the same way as a game developer using nVidia should work on AMD because both use DirectX.

Comment: @joyrex I'm referring to _official_ support via a _unified_ API